# How can I download iTunes 12.6.4.3?

Tags: itunes

I am trying to find and install iTunes version 12.6.4.3. However, it only seems like you can get version 12.6.4 from Apple's website.

Where can I download iTunes 12.6.4.3?

[This](https://bbs.feng.com/read-htm-tid-11704694.html) Chinese website seems to provide a download link to it on Apple's servers, but it seems as though the download was pulled.

Comment: Have you seen [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079)? My understanding is that the version you can download from this page is 12.6.4.3, although I haven't checked it in a while.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives you iTunes 12.6.4 for some odd reason!

Comment: Interesting. The page hasn't been updated since 4 April 2018, so you'd think that'd be the version that was released as per this [MacRumors article](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/04/04/itunes-12-6-4-released/) of the same date. Maybe it's still the same version but without the .3 at the end being referenced?

Comment: Confirmed (at least for the PC version) the download link gives you the version you are looking for.